# MongoDB link documents from one collection and then read its queue

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save some directories structure to my database, so I have data model like dir: { name, parent_dir }. But if I need a full path then I mush to make mongodb queries to watch every directory parent while it isnt root, like  /parent_dir/parent_dir/parent_dir/dir. But the thing is It will be too much useless queries. Can I get full queue of directories with only one mongodb query?

Comment: If you absolutely must save this structure to a database, then I suggest you use a graph database. It makes path querying simpler and optimized. Here's a list of graph dbs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database#List_of_graph_databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you may want to check out [Models tree structures](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/), especially [materialized paths](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/) section.

Where as an example, you can store the paths like below:

```
db.categories.insert( { _id: "parent_A", path: null } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "parent_B", path: ",parent_A," } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "parent_C", path: ",parent_A,parent_B," } )
```

Although this pattern requires additional steps of working with strings and regular expressions, the pattern also provides more flexibility in working with the path, such as finding nodes by partial paths.

Hope that helps.